# ExpressJS get post parameter and usage of external javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

im trying to create a simple webpage with some server side functions but somehow 2 things arent working as they supposed to work.

via html button im running a clientside javascript that does a http post request.
Client side javascript

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.open('POST', '/test2')
httpRequest.send(var1,var2,var3,var4);
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var dbFunc = require("./dbFunctions.js");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = 8888;
//allow to use body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//allow to use static files
app.use(express.static("public"));
//listen to smth
app.post('/test2', function (req, res) {
console.log("worked");
});
//start server

app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running on port" + port);
```

My server detects this post http request and does the "console.log" but how do i get the parameters from the http.request as a variable? I tried to work with bodyParser but somehow my object is always empty.

Another thing is, ive created another Javascript file(dbFunctions.js) and also implemented it in the server file but if i try to run a function(dbFunc.test("hello") for example) it says "dbFunc.test is not a function".

dbFunctions.js

```
function DBFunctions(){
    function test(a){
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

Ive also tried to do something like this, but this gave me the same error.

```
function test(a){
console.log(a);
}
```

Could someone give me a hint or tell me what i am missing?

Comment: with `HMLHttpRequest.send()` you need to make sure you pass in what that function expects, it doesn't expect multiple arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Comment: `test` inside `DBFunctions` cannot be accessed by `test.DBFunctions`

Answer (score 1):

**Answer1:**

The way you are sending data into post request is wrong, you slould send in format of,
  **`xhttp.send("val1=val1&val2=val2");`**

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.open('POST', '/test2')
httpRequest.send(var1=var1&var2=var2&var3=var2&var3=var3);
```

**To POST data like an HTML form, add an HTTP header with setRequestHeader(). Specify the data you want to send in the send() method:**

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.open('POST', '/test2')
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpRequest.send(var1=var1&var2=var2&var3=var2&var3=var3);
```

In your `server.js`, use `req.body` to get those values.

```
app.post('/test2', function (req, res) {
    console.log("worked");
    console.log(req.body)
  });
```

[XMLHttp request example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

**Answer2:**

From your `dbFunctions.js` file you should export your function using **module exports in node js**.

**dbFunctions.js:**

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.test = function(a) {
  console.log(a);
};
```

You can also do as,

```
module.exports = {
  test: function(a) {
    console.log(a)
  },
}
```

Now in your **`server.js`**

```
var dbFunc = require("./dbFunctions.js");

dbFunc.test();
```

[Node js module exports](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

All your posted variables will be available in `req.body` try `console.log(req.body)`.

Secondly you most probably not exporting `test` function from `dbFunction.js`, that's why getting "dbFunc.test is not a function" because `dbFunc.test` is `undefined`.

Note: As mentioned in one of the comment, you need to use `httpRequest.send(var1,var2,var3,var4);` in the right way. It does not expect multiple parameters.

Like: `httpRequest.send("var=var1&var1=var2")`

> Please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send